# Symfony2: automatically login user with FosRestBundle and LdapClient

Tags: php, symfony, authentication, fosrestbundle

I'm trying to implement FosRestBundle with LdapClient in my Symfony 2.8 application. I want to auto login my LDAP user when application starts and using this user credentials i want to search other REST api user's informations.

I've creadet service and security based on
[Authenticating against an LDAP server from security component](http://symfony.com/doc/current/security/ldap.html)   and [Ldap Component informations from Symfony Blog](http://symfony.com/blog/new-in-symfony-2-8-ldap-component).

My ldap service looks like this:

```
ldap:
    class: Symfony\Component\Ldap\LdapClient
    arguments:
        - ldap.myserver.com   # host
        - 3268         # port
        - 3           # version
        - false       # SSL
        - false        # TLS
```

and my providers:

```
providers:
    ldap_users:
        ldap:
            service: ldap
            base_dn: dc=myportal,dc=url,dc=com
            search_dn: mysuperuser
            search_password: mysuperpassword
            filter: (sAMAccountName={username})
            default_roles: ROLE_USER
```

And my firewall:

```
firewalls:
    api:
        provider: ldap_users
        stateless: true
        pattern:    ^/api
        http_basic_ldap:
            service: ldap
            dn_string: "{username}@mydaomain.domain.com"
```

Configuration is preety staightforward, I want all `/api` url's to be provided by lsdap service and I want use ldap provider credentials.

Now when I'm trying to get on my `http://localhost:8399/api/v1/users/1` url I'm getting information from browser that Authentication is required and I have to provide username and password . In `dev.log` file I can see

```
[2016-12-21 14:23:53] request.INFO: Matched route "application_app_v1_user_getuser". {"route_parameters":{"_controller":"Application\\AppBundle\\Controller\\V1\\UserController::getUserAction","id":"1","_route":"application_app_v1_user_getuser"},"request_uri":"http://localhost:8399/api/v1/users/1"} []
[2016-12-21 14:23:53] security.INFO: An AuthenticationException was thrown; redirecting to authentication entry point. {"exception":"[object] (Symfony\\Component\\Security\\Core\\Exception\\AuthenticationCredentialsNotFoundException(code: 0): A Token was not found in the TokenStorage. at /var/www/symfony/backend/vendor/symfony/symfony/src/Symfony/Component/Security/Http/Firewall/AccessListener.php:53)"} []
[2016-12-21 14:23:53] security.DEBUG: Calling Authentication entry point. [] []
```

My question is , how to enable autologin to application using Symfony LdapClient and with credentials from provider and service.

Comment: I'm not sure I got your question. The purpose of the LDAP authentication is to actually "store / retrieve" users to / from your LDAP directory. The idea of the `http_basic_ldap` firewall is to map an HTTP Basic authentication asking for username / password and automagically check the credential against LDAP. So when making a request to your `/api` you must provide a valid username/password. If you want to automatically "login" the called user identified by the id `1` as in your example when requested it is a different thing. Please clarify.

Comment: Hi, i want to automatically login 'mysuperuser' to an app when any other user is requesting /api url. 'mysuperuser'  is readonly user to retrieve other user's information. So if I understand whole read only users 'philosophy'  there should be no information that username and password are needed to get my api url

Comment: then I think you misunderstand several concepts. You probably don't need to set up any security firewall to do what you want, and just use your LDAP Client to fetch user's data. The purpose of the `provider` is to say to the Symfony Security layer where your "registered" users are stored and where it needs to fetch them to test their credentials (if any). It looks like you just want to fetch users from an LDAP directory and provide the data to an API without securing it.